# zappa is ignoring flask project log messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, zappa, python-zappa

I have a flask project which i want to deploy on aws environment using zappa.

i packaged my flask application and placed in S3. my ci/cd will take care of running this packaged file as a lambda.

**Issue:**

Basically my flask project contains custom logging messages, whenever i run flask application, it used to log the data.
But whenever i deploy my flask application on lambda using zappa, lambda is running but it is not logging any of my custom logging messages present in my flask application.

I tried these `zappa_settings.json` but no success.

```
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "main.app",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "project_name": "my-project",
        "runtime": "python3.8",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-bucket-12345",
        "log_level" : "DEBUG",
        "cloudwatch_log_level": "INFO",
        "cloudwatch_data_trace": true
}}
```

**Can anyone suggest a solution for this?**

Comment: Same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: no. i gave up to this zappa